# ** BUILD FAILED ** The following build commands failed: CompileC 'npx react-native run-ios'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator

When I create a brand new project using *npx react-native init <Project_Name>*, it doesn't run when using the *npx react-native run-ios*. Like the command is supposed to do, the app should build and start running on the iOS Simulator. I'm using a MacBook Air 2020 with the processor being 1.1GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 and has 8GB memory. I'm getting this error message instead:

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/vawesome/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test4-eeynbnaaulduvdaotexpgrsehmgl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/vawesome/test4/test4/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Flipper' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

**So far, I've tried**:

Deleting Podfile and re-installing it

Creating a new project

Re-setting up my environment

**Here Is My Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: no, i had no other choice but to scrap my project, i spent hundreds of dollars for external help but to no avail.

Comment: Try clearing DerivedData too. Location: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData